# Show that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly for all $z$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, uniform-convergence

Show that the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly for all $z$.

I know that the definition for uniform convergence is: We say ${_}$ converges to  uniformly on a subset  of Ω iff for every $>0$ there is an $_0∈ℕ$ so that if $>_0$ then $|_()−()|<$ for all $∈$.

BUT I'm not sure if I can use it the same for a power series or if there are different rules with that. Can I?
Also, what would the f(z) be for this? I get that $f_n(z)=\frac{z^n}{n!}$, but how do I get $f(z)$?

Comment: It doesn't converge uniformly. I think you must have miscopied the question.

Comment: "Converges uniformly for all z" is a bit ambiguous and doesn't quite make sense. Uniform convergence is defined on sets (subsets of the domain). Here, you can show that it converges uniformly on any bounded set, but not on $\mathbb C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When considering series of functions such as $z \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(z)$, you take $f_n$ as the partial sum :
$$
f_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n g_k(z).
$$

However, the exponential series does not converge uniformaly on all $\mathbb C$. It does however uniformly converges on every bounded subset of $\mathbb C$. Indeed, if $|z| \leq M$ :

$$
\left| \frac{z^n}{n!} \right| = \frac{|z|^n}{n!} \leq \frac{M^n}{n!}
$$

and the series $\sum_n \frac{M^n}{n!}$ converges (its sum is $e^M$).

Is that clearer?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! But could you explain how you found $\frac{M^n}{n!}$ converges?

Comment: One way to see this is that by comparison we have $n^2 \frac{M^n}{n!} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$ so there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, $n^2 \frac{M^n}{n!} \leq 1$ i.e. $\frac{M^n}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Since $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, then $\sum_n \frac{M^n}{n!}$ also converges by series comparison

Answer (score 1):

No, power series have nothing special that would require a different handling.

You have a sequence of functions of $z$ that are the partial sums

$$f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{k!}.$$

Pointwise convergence is verified by the ratio test,

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{z^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\dfrac{z^k}{k!}}=\frac zk<r<1$$ which is true for $k>x$. But as you see, this condition is based a relation between $z$ and $k$ and there cannot be an $n_0$ that works for all $z$.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the convergence is **not** uniform on $\Bbb C$.
Here's how one could show that.

---

Suppose that it was. Then, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{z^k}{k!} - e^z\right| < 1 \quad (*)$$
for all $z \in \Bbb C$.

We now show that there exists $z_0 \in \Bbb R$ for which $(*)$ is not true.

Note that $e^x \to 0$ as $x\to-\infty$.
Thus, there exists $M < 0$ such that $e^{x} < 1$ for all $x < M$.

On the other hand, note that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{z^k}{k!}$ is a polynomial and thus, $\left|\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{z^k}{k!}\right| \to \infty$ as $z \to -\infty$.

Thus, we can find a real $z_0 < M$ such that $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{z_0^k}{k!}\right| > 43.$$ For this $z_0$, we also have that $e^{z_0} < 1$. Therefore, we see that

$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{z_0^k}{k!} - e^{z_0}\right| \ge \left|\sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{z_0^k}{k!}\right| - |e^{z_0}| > 43 - 1 > 1,$$
giving us the promised contradiction!

Comment: Why is 43 here?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal: I needed some number greater than 1, 43 is as good a choice as anything.

Comment: I see. That's what I suspected